# Chrome browser has started core dumping on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome

I have previously downloaded and installed the Chrome (not Chromium) Version 52.0.2743.82 (64-bit) browser. It has worked in the past (I use Chromium as my primary browser). But today it will not launch. I removed it and re-installed it and the problem continues. If I launch it from the command line it says that it core dumps. I don't know where the core file goes. It isn't in the directory where I tried to run chrome, or in my home directory (not that I would know what to do with it).

I need Chrome to watch Amazon Video (they won't allow Chromium as a browser). I could watch them on another computer, but it is disturbing that a program has all of a sudden stopped working. I don't believe that I installed any program between when it last worked and when it stopped working.

Edit:

I was asked to add the message that displays in the terminal. Here it is along with the command I issued:

```
google-chrome-stable
Aborted (core dumped)
```

This output is coming from Linux, not Chrome, as redirecting the Chrome output produces an empty output.txt file and the same output on the terminal:

```
google-chrome-stable > output.txt  2>&1 
Aborted (core dumped)
```

**Edit2:** I found a solution as the answer to this question:
[Google Chrome not starting ("Aborted (core dumped)")](https://askubuntu.com/questions/803068/14-04-google-chrome-not-starting-aborted-core-dumped)

The solution is to delete the file **~/.gtk-2.0**

I don't know if it matters, but this is what was in that file:

```
include "/usr/share/themes/oxygen-gtk/gtk-2.0/gtkrc"

gtk-theme-name="oxygen-gtk"
```

Comment: @DavidFoerster Added.

Comment: This question is wrongly duplicated with the NSS issue. It is the same as http://askubuntu.com/questions/803068/14-04-google-chrome-not-starting-aborted-core-dumped

Comment: @PeterSmit Deleting ~/gtk-2.0 worked for me too. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Chrome not starting (“Aborted (core dumped)”)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/803068/google-chrome-not-starting-aborted-core-dumped)

Answer (score 1):

Before you start Chrome again, delete the following directories:

`~/.config/google-chrome`
`~/.cache/google-chrome`

This will reset Chrome to its default settings and delete any file that may be corrupted and cause this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately it still does it after deleting those directories.

Comment: Don't know why as there were only 2 benign looking lines in it, but the solution was to delete ~/.gtk-2.0