# Google Chrome not starting ("Aborted (core dumped)")

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, crash

My Google Chrome stopped working mysteriously. When I run it from a terminal I get:

```
$ google-chrome-stable
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I installed google chrome via de [Debian package](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/) and I am running a 64-bit machine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Chrome error: Error initializing NSS without a persistent database](http://askubuntu.com/questions/801838/google-chrome-error-error-initializing-nss-without-a-persistent-database)

Comment: For the `apt-get` warning: [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](/q/65911/175814)

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson: Why do you believe that is the same issue? The terminal output is quite different.

Comment: @DavidFoerster: I assumed that the terminal output in the question I stated as a duplicate also includes "Aborted (core dumped)". See for instance http://askubuntu.com/questions/803173/aborted-core-dumped-google-chrome

Comment: I managed to disable the packages that could not be fetched, I disabled them via the software centre and I no longer get that message when I type `sudo apt-get update` although the problem persists (after re-installing google chrome).

Comment: Did you test the solution at http://askubuntu.com/a/802997/159370 ?

Comment: there's no nss directory on /usr/lib/. Shall I then create one and add the soft link?

Comment: That's worth a try, IMO. Otherwise I think this is a temporary issue which will be fixed in the next update of Google Chrome.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and someone advised me to remove `~/.gtkrc-2.0` which did fix it for me. No idea why though.

Comment: As you’re a reputation 11 user: if this answers your question, don’t forget to click the grey ☑ under the “0” at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means “yes, this answer is valid”!

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, I am affraid of deleting a file which I do not know what is it for...

Comment: @BCArg You can try renaming the directory to something else instead of deleting it: `mv ~/.gtkrc-2.0 ~/.gtkrc-2.0.bak`.

Comment: I installed Chromium instead and will leave like that, it is exactly like Chrome

Comment: @BCArg: Are you saying that the issue is not present in Chromium?

Comment: That's right, Chromium is running absolutely fine.

Comment: Did work for me. After renaming the file, tried to start /usr/bin/google-chrome. It gave permission issue with ~/.config/google-chrome folder. That folder was owned by root. After changing the ownership, chrome started fine.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of people have said that removing `~/.gtkrc-2.0` would do the trick. I had the same problem but I had no such file! Uninstalling and installing chrome also doesn't help.

Turns out, when Chrome crashes sometimes the **User Data Directory** can get corrupted. So to fix it I did the following:

1. Uninstall chrome `apt-get purge google-chrome-stable`
2. Install chrome http://chrome.google.com
3. Remove the cache and configuration folders. 
   `rm -rf /home/<<your username>>/.config/google-chrome/`
   and `rm -rf /home/<<your username>>/.cache/google-chrome/`
4. Start Chrome and enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem for both chromium and chrome.
I just removed their respective config directories:

- for chromium

  rm -rf ~/.config/chromium*
- for chrome

  rm -rf ~/.config/google-chrome

and everything worked again.