# Google Chrome does not start: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, segmentation-fault

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.02 LTS. Today after starting the machine, I am unable to start Google Chrome. The version is latest as downloaded from Google. It prints an error as follows:

*Segmentation fault (core dumped)*

I have tried reinstalling google chrome, and trying the answers as mentioned in the following link 
[Google Chrome not starting ("Aborted (core dumped)")](https://askubuntu.com/questions/803068/google-chrome-not-starting-aborted-core-dumped)

The problem is same if I install Chromium. As of now nothing works. 
Fresh installation of Ubuntu to me is a big headache. Can anyone help and provide some answers.

Comment: hmmm have you tried an older version of crhome? (as in not the latest)

Comment: I do not have an older version of chrome with me. Is there any link to download older versions of chrome?

Comment: you might try here https://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php and proceed with the install as normal

Comment: It is working with an older version!!. Currently using google-chrome version 71, with no 'segmentation fault' error.

Comment: I would suggest asking on something like the mailing list for google chrome then as it is a third party application not supported by ubuntu

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/690565/how-to-resolve-segmentation-fault-core-dumped)

Answer (score -1):

It's a known sandboxing issue. Start chrome with

```
google-chrome-stable  --no-sandbox
```

Comment: What's the implications of not using sandbox?